# Defer loading of javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, pagespeed

To defer Javascript, I use the following code. It works.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element2 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
var element3 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "js/jquery.idTabs.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
var element4 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "js/mobilemelody.jq.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
var element5 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "js/swipe.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
var element6 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "js/swipe.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
var element7 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "js/mobilemelody.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
var element8 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

Now i have start to use cloudfront cdn,  and server the js files from subdomain content.exemple.com.
The subdomain content.exemple.com point to cloudfront cdn.
Exemple js/bootstrap.min.js have become http://content.exemple.com/js/bootstrap.min.js
i have used the following code without any result :

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function downloadJSAtOnload() {
var element2 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "//s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-515d67835fedfa10#";
document.body.appendChild(element);
var element3 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
var element4 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "http://content.exemple.com/min/?f=templates/default/js/bootstrap.min.js,templates/default/js/jquery.cookee.js,templates/default/js/jquery.validate.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
var element5 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "http://exemple.avimeo.com/min/?f=templates/default/js/jquery.maskedinput-1.3.min.js,templates/default/js/jquery.tagsinput.min.js,templates/default/js/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js,templates/default/js/jquery.uniform.min.js,templates/default/js/jquery.ba-dotimeout.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
var element6 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "js/swipe.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
var element7 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "http://content.exemple.com/js/jquery.typewatch.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
var element8 = document.createElement("script");
element.src = "http://content.exemple.com/min/?f=templates/default/js/waypoints.min.js,templates/default/js/melody.social.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(element);
}
if (window.addEventListener)
window.addEventListener("load", downloadJSAtOnload, false);
else if (window.attachEvent)
window.attachEvent("onload", downloadJSAtOnload);
else window.onload = downloadJSAtOnload;
</script>
```

i hope that someone can help thanks

Comment: If you are loading jquery dynamically, you cannot use jquery-deferreds to control the process.

Comment: Do you get any error in the console? I guess it was a good scenario description but "it does not work" is not a good explanation.

Comment: BTW... Set the `src` attribute of the proper `"script"` elements... You really should look at the console... This will initially trigger an error whit a message that will point at your problem... and the first code have the same problem... I think it was a problem when CTRL+C CTRL+V some code... it was your code?

Comment: @prusse no noy my code

Comment: @prusse google page speed suggestion show the following message : Your page has 9 blocking script resources it means that the code not working

Comment: @Prusse google page speed suggestion show the following message : Your page has 9 blocking script resources it means that the code not working

Comment: Using Chome? Press F12. FireFox? Press Shift+F5 or install FireBug and press F12. IE (8+ my guess)? Press F12. Then got to the "console" tab. There is the error message you want.

Comment: the error SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: @Prusse SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: The posted code should not trigger that error. Guess you have more wrong stuff to solve somewhere in your file.